# getString("android.text") returns SpannableString instead of String

Tags: android, kotlin, android-notifications

I'm trying to get notification content using:

```
val sender = sbn.notification.extras.getString("android.title")
val msg = sbn.notification.extras.getString("android.text")
```

`android.title` returns the desired value, but `android.text` returns `null`.

Upon debugging, I found out:

```
W/Bundle: Key android.text expected String but value was a android.text.SpannableString. The default value <null> was returned.
W/Bundle: Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.text.SpannableString cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

Why `android.text` is returning `SpannableString`? And how can I convert it to `String` in this case?

Comment: try to concatenate it with an empty string or use `toString()` and see if it solves the issue

Comment: try this  remoteMessage.notification?.title
        remoteMessage.notification?.body

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Retrieving SpannableString**

If you cannot control what is put in the intent extras you should be able to retrieve it with the following code:

```
val msg = sbn.notification.extras.getCharSequence("android.text").toString()
```

Note that `SpannableString` class extends `CharSequence`.

**Adding extras**

Wherever you are adding the extras *make sure* that you do not add a SpannableString but the string itself!

For example, for an editText:

```
var editText: EditText = ...

extras.put("android.text", editText.text) // this will put an Editable which is a Spannable and not a string

extras.put("android.text", editText.text.toString()) // this puts a string
```

---

Comment: I'm getting the *extras* from the notification. So I'm not adding them myself.

Comment: I have updated the answer, please let me know if this helps